# Hashmap contains key return false even when key exists

Tags: java, android, data-structures, hashmap, containskey

I have made a hashmap `Map percentages= new HashMap();`, I have entered values and keys into it and that was successful, but when I try to get the or try ContainsKey method then it returns false.

Please see the attached screen shot:[image]

Comment: would you like to show your code ?

Comment: would you please show you code?

Comment: Without code, we can't tell what you did wrong.  For all we know, maybe you have a string of `42` as a key in the `HashMap`, and are trying to do a `ContainsKey()` with an integer `42`.  That's just one way you could have gotten it wrong.  And if your post is to be believed, doesn't look like you are using a typed `HashMap`, so it is quite possible. Or maybe you are experiencing a subtle bug related to auto boxing. Who knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning values to Map, you may used different datatype and when checking for key, you are using integer, it won't work.

```
Map a = new HashMap();
    a.put("1", 12);
    a.put("2", 32);

    System.out.println(a.containsKey(1));
```

This will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

you are calling contains on new ArrayList object and not on Map

Comment: But that new ArrayList is supposed to contain map key set right ?

Comment: I tried calling containsKey on the map at first see the image